# calling PHP based service from inside the Excel (using macro)

Tags: php, excel, communication, excel-2003

I would like to call a PHP based web service every time cell in column A is added or modified and write the resuts to collumns B,C,D

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some tutorials on doing this, such as [Consuming Web Services from Excel 2003](http://weblogs.asp.net/erobillard/archive/2005/07/22/420289.aspx)